# Is there any python keyword for replacing last decimal point from a number string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace the decimal point with null except last decimal
eg:

```
number="123.34.56.04"
```

I need to delete `123.34.56` and need to get the final answer as `.04`
anyone, please help me to out of this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at `rpartition` or `rsplit`.

Comment: `''.join(number.rpartition('.')[1:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.rpartition('.')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to split the string by the right most `'.'`:

```
>>> number="123.34.56.04"
>>> number.rpartition('.')
('123.34.56', '.', '04')
```

Then use `.join` to reform the number:

```
>>> ''.join(number.rpartition('.')[1:])
'.04'
```

This works as expected even if there is no `'.'`:

```
>>> ''.join('1234'.rpartition('.')[1:])
'1234'
```

Comment: yes its working fine so if I partitioned these string is there any chance to get the first part?? like 123.34.56

Comment: Yes -- `number.rpartition('.')[0]` would return `'123.34.56'`

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the `number` using the dot as a separator and then get the last value. The `number` variable needs to be a string:

```
number = "123.34.56.04"
list1 = number.split(".")
last_number = list1[-1] # to get the last value
```